# Calculating Flux of a surface

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I have to calculate the flux a surface but I don't really find the way to parametrize the surface. Moreover, I am not sure if I have to use Gauss theorem or Stoke's theorem. 
This is my exercise :

Let be $F = (xy + yz + zx, \cos(xyz), xy - xz + \cos(xyz) - 2x)$ a vector field.

$V = \{(x,y,z)| 0\le x, y, z \le 1\}$ (the cube) and $L$ is the surface intersection between the boundary of $V$ and the plane $y + z = 3/2$.

So, I have to calculate the integral over $L$ of $F$.

Thank you !

Comment: Maybe L is the surface intersection of...?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your modifications. L is the surface intersection of the cube and the plane V

Comment: If you don't know what to apply, please show your thoughts(doesn't matter if they are correct or not) on this question. Else, I am afraid this question might get closed as off-topic for the lack of context.

Comment: @MichaelR Are you also sure that the sign for $\cos (xyz)$ terms are correct?

Comment: Yes it's is correct

Answer (score 1):

We need to evaluate

$$\iint_L \vec F \cdot \vec n \, dS$$

where

- $\vec n=\pm \frac1{\sqrt 2}(0,1,1)$ depending on the choosen orientation
- $\vec F \cdot \vec n =\pm \frac1{\sqrt 2}\left(2\cos (xyz)+xy-xz-2x\right)$ with $z=\frac32-y$
- $dS = \sqrt 2 \, dx\, dy$ with $0\le x\le 1$ and $\frac12\le y \le 1$

Comment: Are you sure that integral is not a double integral?

Comment: @paulplusx Yes of course it is a double integral on the surface $L$. Mybe the symbol used is not clear? I add an other integral symbol.

Comment: About the orientation : it's not very important because he asked only the absolute value.

Comment: @gimusi, when i want to compute the double integral as you wrote, i have a problem because I can't find the integral of cos(xy*(3/2 - y)).

Comment: @MichaelR For that reason I asked to check the sign for that terms. I think we need a numerical evaluation.

Comment: Yes you right. But what I thought at the beginning was to parametrize the interior of the surface which is bounded by L with the polar coordinates

Comment: @MichaelR I don't think that way should be effective. $L$ is a rectangle and I can't think to obtain an easier derivation by different parametrizations. Do you know the numerical final solution?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: @MichaelR There was a typo for dS. By [numerical evaluation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+2cos(xy(3%2F2-y))%2Bxy-x(3%2F2-y)-2x+dx+dy+x%3D0..1,+y%3D1%2F2..1) we obtain $\approx 0.452$